# How to insert a new line in a UILabel that uses NSString StringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am using a `UILabel` in my storyboard to show a string of text. Then I am using `dispatch_get_main_queue` to change the text in the UILabel. The text is being cut off on-screen after `dispatch_get_main_queue` is being called. I have also tried `\n` which deletes the rest of the text completely.

```
/*slide*/
double delayInSecond8 = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime8 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSecond8 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime8, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    hello.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You can also share\n your email address here"];

});
```

How can I add a new line to this method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your label to display multiple lines you need to specify that in its [numberOfLines](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) property:

> This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

You could set it either in code or in Attributes inspector in the storyoard:
[image]

Also make sure that the constraints of the label allows it to expand accordingly to its content.

Comment: After making an auto layout adjustment allowing for further width of the UILabel and changing `Lines` to 2 in the storyboard, it still gets cut off. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @programcode check if the [lineBreakMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620525-linebreakmode) property of the label is set to `byWordWrapping`. If this doesn't help then I'd check the constraints again - you can test it directly in the interface builder by adding long text to the label's text and see how it's handling it.